# Shaking nil from false in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want the following outcome:
"1" -> true
"0" -> false
nil -> nil

How can this function be improved?

```
#(when-not (nil? %) (if %  "1" "0"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your requirement translates directly into a map and maps are also callable as functions in Clojure, so `{1 true, 0 false}` is the function you want.

```
({1 true, 0 false} 1) ;;=> true
({1 true, 0 false} 0) ;;=> false
({1 true, 0 false} nil) ;;=> nil
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!